# Support for .NET 6 in WixNetfxExtension

Tags: .net, wix, wix4

I am building an installer in Wix 3.14. I want to check if the .NET 6 runtime is already installed, and if not, offer a way to install it by downloading it (I don't want to include the .NET 6 runtime in the installer).

I found the following documentation of the WixNetfxExtension: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension/

However, it only mentions .NET Framework, not .NET Core or .NET 5+. No matter how I search, I find no mentions of it whatsoever. Is there support for doing what I want for .NET 5+ with WixNetfxExtension?

I would be willing to upgrade to Wix 4, but I found no mentions of WixNetfxExtension at all in the Wix 4 documentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All the WiX v4 documentation on .NET, including detecting .NET Core/.NET >=5, is available at https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/wixext/dotnet/.

Comment: But this documentation doesn't mention how to let Wix setup an installer for the .NET 6 runtime for me, like "NetFx481Redist" but for .NET 6. It doesn't even mention if it is possible at all, and I cannot find the answer.

Comment: It doesn't support it because the .NET redistributables change every month.

Comment: Sure, but I want to offer the user a way to download the latest one in the installation process. Which is the way I interpret e.g. NetFx452Web, but for .NET Framework 4.5.2 instead.

Comment: That's not built-in.